# Discord Bot: Why this bot can read DM but doesn't give the role in the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot that can give a Example role in the MIAO server if the user type in BOT dm the right email with "@" before the email (like @example@gmail.com)

```
async def on_message(message):
    #Check if the message is a DM
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        #Check if the message starts with "@"
      if message.content.startswith("@"):
          email = message.content
           # Check if the email is in the database
          if email in email_database:
            # If the email is in the database, then give the user the Example role
            server = message.guild
            role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Example')
            await message.author.add_roles(role)
            await message.channel.send('Email found in the database! You have been given the Example role!')
          else:
            # If the email is not in the database, then tell the user that the email was not found
            await message.channel.send('Email not found in the database!')
```

I'm sure about the email database (I insert the code before these lines).

How can I solve this problem? Do i have to specify which server?

Answer (score 1):

If the message is sent in a DM then `message.guild` is going to be `None`. I'm assuming you're getting an error message. You'll have to get the `guild` and then the member in the guild and apply the role that way.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #Check if the message is a DM
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        #Check if the message starts with "@"
        if message.content.startswith("@"):
            email = message.content
            # Check if the email is in the database
            if email in email_database:
                # If the email is in the database, then give the user the Example role
                
                # change `client` to `bot` or whatever your client/bot object is called
                server = await client.fetch_guild(YOUR_GUILD_ID)
                role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name='Example')
                # change this to `await server.fetch_member` if you keep getting None but you're _certain_ they exist
                # shouldn't be necessary though as we're fetching the guild
                server_member = server.get_member(message.author.id)
                if not server_member:
                    # user doesn't exist in guild
                    return
                await server_member.add_roles(role)
                await message.channel.send('Email found in the database! You have been given the Example role!')
            else:
                # If the email is not in the database, then tell the user that the email was not found
                await message.channel.send('Email not found in the database!')
```